# Issue with autoresizing in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, autoresize

I have an xib file with the image like this:

When I run it, it seems to downsize to this:

Width:320 Height:370 is the values I have given. There is a navigation bar above and a tab bar below.

Should the image show normally? it seems to be resized.. not sure why...

How do I avoid the shrinking?

Need some guidance.. Thanks...

**EDIT1 **

Huge apologies.. I am using iPhone(Retina 3.5 inch). that is why it is appearing  on the middle. How do i ensure that it remains at the bottom for iphone(Retina 4 inch), iPhone (Retina 3.5 inch) and iPhone?

**EDIT2 **

in iphone 5, it looks like this:

How to avoid this?

Comment: still not able to resize the image...

Answer (score 0):

please add bottom bar as tabbar in xib file ... 
 [image: put bottom bar on xib file]

Comment: still the same... it gets resized... not sure why?

Answer (score 0):

Open your xib and select your view then Uncheck the "Use AutoLayout" property from 
File Inspector(Option+Command+1)

Comment: "Use AutoLayout" was checked by Default ,uncheck it.It happens when we deal with both 3.5 inch and 4 inch displays.Its little tricky to handle with Autoresizing,it becomes messy. Rather you can set views frame programmatically,differentiating between display sizes.

Comment: it was not clicked at all. I am upgrading my app to iphone 5... so it was not there intitally...

Answer (score 0):

Select the image in the xib editor and set the mode to "top".

Answer (score 0):

You need to set autoresizingmask of your view and imageview to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin if you want they stay bottom all the time.

And you need to remove UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight.

You can do it with code or in interfacebuilder.